# SQL Tasks Table with updates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, task, view

So I'm automating my tasks, the final product is a view where I get a simple tasklist and the last column is the last update for that task. I've tried joining those tables but they receive all updates and I want only the most recent ones, I know the dates are the same (i've inserted them all with GETDATE() as date value).

I can't figure out a way to get all columns from the Tasks table and only the "Last update" from the Tasks_Updates table.

Here's some simple data from both:

[These are my tables, one for tasks, one for task updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snip.jpg)

This is my view's code, I know it's simple, i've tried (select top 1 [column]) and it didn't work, I've also tried grouping values with no solution

```
SELECT        
dbo.TSKM_tsk.TASKID, 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.DATE, 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.[RAISED BY], 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.NAME, 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.[DUE DATE], 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.DESCRIPTION, 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.STATUS, 
dbo.TSKM_updates.uDESCRIPTION

FROM
dbo.TSKM_tsk INNER JOIN
dbo.TSKM_updates ON dbo.TSKM_tsk.TASKID = dbo.TSKM_updates.rTask
```

The final product is like this picture, but only with the last update, not all updates from the updates table:

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snip.jpg)

I thank you guys very much in advance!

Comment: Thanks to @AT-2016 I feel like i'm one step closer, I can now see only lines ferering to tasks, meaning 1 update for each, but I'm seeing only one update for all rows.

Comment: Here's what I've got so far

[link]https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/v/t34.0-12/14696904_1271081789580018_1559710457_n.png?oh=dd2845793ec9646568e5aac7ab564978&oe=57FFFFDF&__gda__=1476321041_4223cec7113f577a5bcbe6a152e6b569

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly what I needed, thanks AT!

The working code is

```
SELECT        
dbo.TSKM_tsk.TASKID, 
dbo.TSKM_tsk.DATE,  
dbo.TSKM_tsk.NAME,  
dbo.TSKM_tsk.DESCRIPTION,  
(SELECT TOP 1 [uDESCRIPTION] from [_dbWEB].[dbo].[TSKM_updates] WHERE rTask = dbo.TSKM_tsk.TASKID ORDER BY UID DESC) as [LAST UPDATE]

FROM
dbo.TSKM_tsk LEFT JOIN
dbo.TSKM_updates ON dbo.TSKM_tsk.TASKID = dbo.TSKM_updates.rTask
group by TASKID, date, NAME, DESCRIPTION, STATUS, [_dbWEB].[dbo].    [TSKM_updates].rTask
```

Comment: The above query is almost identical to mine but it should do. Glad to know worked :)